# Spring websocket - how to get number of sessions

Tags: java, spring, stomp-websocket

I'm using [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) tutorial and I'm trying to figure out how to get the number of current sessions.

My WebSocketConfig looks like this (copy and paste from the tutorial) :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

I'd like to know the number of sessions inside of this class (again copy and paste):

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {


    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }

}
```

Is there an easy way to get the number of current sessions(users, connections) to the websocket?

Edit:

**Here is my solution:**

```
Set<String> mySet = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Boolean>());

@EventListener
private void onSessionConnectedEvent(SessionConnectedEvent event) {
    StompHeaderAccessor sha = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());
    mySet.add(sha.getSessionId());
}

@EventListener
private void onSessionDisconnectEvent(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
    StompHeaderAccessor sha = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());
    mySet.remove(sha.getSessionId());
}
```

I can now get the number of Sessions with `mySet.size()` .

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `SimpUserRegistry` and its `getUserCount()` method instead of handling connections manually.

Example:

```
@Autowired
private SimpUserRegistry simpUserRegistry;

public int getNumberOfSessions() {
    return simpUserRegistry.getUserCount();
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use **ApplicationContext** events. Every connection, subscription or other action will fire a special event: **SessionConnectEvent**, **SessionConnectedEvent**, **SessionSubscribeEvent** and so on.

Full doc is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-appplication-context-events). When one of these events fires, you can handle it with your own logic.

**Sample code for reference:**

```java
@EventListener(SessionConnectEvent.class)
public void handleWebsocketConnectListner(SessionConnectEvent event) {
    logger.info("Received a new web socket connection : " + now());
}

@EventListener(SessionDisconnectEvent.class)
public void handleWebsocketDisconnectListner(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
    logger.info("session closed : " + now());
}
```