# How to detect if there is no subscriber to a websocket channel

Tags: java, spring

My spring boot app has an external agent that produces some information and send it to a websocket channel. Is there a way (e.g. event, etc.) to know when no one is actually subscribing to a channel ?

I know that I can implement `ApplicationListener<SessionDisconnectEvent>` and override `onApplicationEvent(SessionDisconnectEvent evt)` but then I have to keep the count of subscribers which imposes a lot of concurrency issues to take care of.

I was wondering if Spring provides such mechanism itself, or if there is any example that I can take a look at.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50467499/9570144

Comment: That question is different. I don't want to the number of user sessions. I want to be notified when everyone left a channel.